# Connecting RDS database from out side of VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, rds, amazon-vpc

My RDS database located in VPC. It's a Multi AZ database so that it's located on two VPC subnet. How could I connect it from outside of VPC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you've placed your RDS instances in a pair of private subnets (as recommended), then you're going to have to spin up a bastion host to access RDS from outside of the VPC.  Please take a look [at this answer](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/faqs/#How_do_I_connect_to_an_RDS_DB_Instance_in_VPC) from the RDS FAQ.

Comment: instead of a bastion host, the docs do say there is a simpler alternative: "To use public connectivity, simply create your DB Instances with the Publicly Accessible option set to yes"  -- but I haven't actually managed to get it to work!

Comment: hwjp - I was just having a similar issue and after changing it to publically accessible (be sure you check 'apply changes now') it worked.